# Two different prices - with different currency - in different countries!

Tags: magento-1.9, price, products

Using Magento, I need some help to display two different prices for one item displayed in two different countries (currency).

The product is displayed:

- in currency A with let's say a price of 100€
- in another currency with a price of 50CHF?

Not only convert from €.

Comment: You may have to create two different websites inside magento store manager to separate 2 Geo locations.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have different prices for the same store but for websites, if you do not use a custom extension which allows this functionality in case you want it.

For the websites you can enable this the following way under

***System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price***

Then you can't show different currencies in admin, only at the frontend.

So what you should do is to create two websites, set different currencies for both. And then in Admin enter both prices in base currency using conversion rate (e.g. 100€ for Website A and 50 CHF for Website B).

Then the conversion will work in the frontend as you described.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I have two websites, and set different currencies for both.

I do not want a base currency using conversion rate, just two different prices for each country. Thank you

Comment: If you have two websites you can change the prices on the product and price level that would work. You might need to do it manually or import the prices with a .csv but that should work. Just try to go into one product pick the correct Store View and set the price, then change the website to the other website and edit the price there.